# ASP.NET MVC Jquery post dynamic form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a HTML form that has two DIVs, one DIV is a fixed area this means that the inputs are not dynamic, and the second DIV is dynamic this means that I have a button that can clone the DIV as many times as a I want.

This is the jquery clode for cloning a new DIV:

```
 $('#btn-addsection').click(function (e) {
                var me = $(this);
                e.preventDefault();

                var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeating-section').last();
                var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(false)
                cloned.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);

                var attrs = ['for', 'id', 'name'];

                var tags = section.find('input, label'),
                    idx = section.index();

                tags.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.is('input')) {
                        $this.val('');
                    }
                    $.each(attrs, function (i, attr) {
                        var attr_val = $this.attr(attr);
                        if (attr_val) {
                            $this.attr(attr, attr_val.replace(/_\d+$/, '_' + (idx)))
                        }
                    })
                })


            });
```

The above code will clone the DIV and will add a underscore "_" plus the next index to the field so I can identify it as a field for a second or third, etc. DIV cloned.

When I post to server I use:

```
 var formData = $('#form-newquote :input').serializeArray();
```

This is my Save method on server:

```
public JsonResult SaveQuote(QuoteModel model)
        {

            var response = this.JsonResponse;

            response = new JsonResponse
            {
                data = null,
                message = string.Empty,
                num = 0,
                success = true,
                code = null
            };

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my `QuoteModel`:

[image]

The red mark is where I will many as many cloned items. My problem is how to send from jquery to server all my dynamic fields so on server I can map them to my `QuoteSelectionMode` object.

Any clue?

Comment: Apart from the fact the `.serializearray()` will not work for properties which are complex properties or collections (it will not even work for a `bool` if you have use `CheckBoxFor()`, you `.replace(..)` code means that you view is not generated correctly in the first place and therefore could never bind to a model. If you want to do this all client side, then you might want to look at the 2nd option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`$('form').serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead. I have never personally used [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). But looking at the documentation, it creates an array of `objects` with `name` and `value` properties which I don't think `ModelBinder` will be able map to the `QuoteModel`.

Changing it to `serialize()` still won't bind your `Sections` property because of how you're handling `name` attribute.

It's crucial to set the `name` attribute  properly whenever you're dealing with properties which are `Collcetions` of objects. In your case, your inputs should be like:

```
<input type="text" name="Sections[0].PropertName" />
<input type="text" name="Sections[0].PropertName2" />
<select name="Sections[0].PropertName3" />
```

When cloned, you should produce this:

```
<input type="text" name="Sections[1].PropertName" />
<input type="text" name="Sections[1].PropertName2" />
<select name="Sections[1].PropertName3" />
```

Besides this, make sure in your ajax, you've given same parameter name as your controller:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ControllerName/SaveQuote",
    data: { model: formData },
    ...........
```

Also, consider using `knockout` for this kind of recurring templates. Cloning using jquery is error-prone and you'll have to write a lot of junk code. In KO, `observalbleArray.push(new viewModel())` and you're set.